# How to embed flickr in silverstripe by shortcodes

Tags: php, flickr, shortcode, silverstripe

**Hello**,

I'm implementing some "shortcodes" in my silverstripe website. For example, i already created some for Youtube, Vimeo and Soundcloud but i can't find a way to add the Flickr one.

Here is a sample code for vimeo :

```
public static function Vimeo($args, $caption = null, $parser = null) {
    if (empty($args['id']))
        return;

    $data = array();
    $data['VimeoID'] = $args['id'];
    $data['autoplay'] = false;
    $data['caption'] = $caption ? Convert::raw2xml($caption) : false;
    $data['width'] = 640;
    $data['height'] = 385;

    $data = array_merge($data, $args);
    $template = new SSViewer('shortcode/Vimeo');
    return $template->process(new ArrayData($data));
```

And this is what i found for flickr :

```
$query = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getInfo&api_key=" . API_KEY . "&photo_id=" . $photoid . "&format=json&nojsoncallback=1";
data = json_decode(file_get_contents($query));

echo "created by: " . data->photo->owner->username;
echo "link to photopage: " . "http://www.flickr.com/photos/" . data->photo->owner->nsid
```

But nothing for the .ss file

Does anybody know how to do it or already did it?

Thanks for help!

Thomas.

Comment: What is the html you want to end up with? I think you should start with that. Then you can turn it into a shortcode where you simply pass in an id variable to make the html change.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi**
I finally found a solution for using the flickr shortcode ->

```
public static function Flickr($args, $caption = null, $parser = null) {

    if (empty($args['set_id']) && empty($args['user_id']))
        return;

    $data = array();

    $data['SET'] = $args['set_id'];
    $data['USER'] = $args['user_id'];


    if (!$scid = SiteConfig::current_site_config()->FlickrClientID) {
        $data['KEY']= $scid = SiteConfig::current_site_config()->FlickrClientID = "id";
    }

    ini_set("flickr", "FLICKR");

    $pics = json_decode(file_get_contents(
            "http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getAllContexts&api_key=".$scid."&format=json&set_id=".$args['set_id']), true);

    $data['ID'] = $pics['id'];


    $data = array_merge($data, $args);
    $template = new SSViewer('shortcode/Flickr');
    return $template->process(new ArrayData($data));
}
```

Using this iframe ->

```
<div class='Flickr clearfix'>
<iframe align="center" src="http://www.flickr.com/slideShow/index.gne?user_id=$USER&set_id=$SET" frameBorder="0" width="500" height="500" scrolling="no"><br /></iframe>
</div>
```

This solution works fine if you want to display some flickr set pictures.
Hope it'll help someone else.

See you